# Cannot locate node of type [ekf_localization_node] in package [robot_localization]

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm new in ROS.
When I tried to run robot_localization package by this command:  roslaunch robot_localization ekf_template.launch
I have met this issue below:

> *ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robot_localization/ekf_localization_node]:
> Cannot locate node of type
> [ekf_localization_node] in package
> [robot_localization]. Make sure file
> exists in package path and permission
> is set to executable (chmod +x)*

I had run these commands before that:

> source devel/setup.bash

and

> source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash

So can I fix it? Many thanks.

[UPDATE] When I used the command:

> rosrun robot_localization
> ekf_localization_node

I got:

> [rosrun] Couldn't find executable
> named ekf_localization_node below
> /home/swarm-robotics/catkin_ws/src/robot_localization

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356330/cannot-locate-node-of-type-%5Bekf_localization_node%5D-in-package-%5Brobot_localization%5D/) by [HieuPham](https://answers.ros.org/users/56377/hieupham/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As per info in your question, you first ran

```
source devel/setup.bash
```

to source your workspace and then:

```
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
```

Which is the cause it's not working.
First run

```
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
```

followed by sourcing your workspace and it should work if everything else is fine.
Also, make sure you ran `catkin_make` in the workspace you have the package in.

---

Originally posted by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) with karma: 463 on 2020-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HieuPham](https://answers.ros.org/users/56377/hieupham/) on 2020-07-04**:
Many thanks,
In my case, if I ran 2 commands follow your guide, it not working but it's ok when I run only source devel/setup.bash
When I ran catkin_make --pkg robot_localization again, it's working correctly. I think when I used catkin_make command previously, I make a few mistakes but I skipped it.